# install-recursive Error 1 ViennaRNA package 2.4.12

Tags: compiling

I am trying to install viennarna package but getting this error - can anyone please solve it?

```
ubuntu@ubuntu-VirtualBox:~/Desktop/ViennaRNA-2.4.12$ make install
Making install in src
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/ubuntu/Desktop/ViennaRNA-2.4.12/src'
Making install in ViennaRNA
make[2]: Entering directory '/home/ubuntu/Desktop/ViennaRNA-2.4.12/src/ViennaRNA'
Making install in static
make[3]: Entering directory '/home/ubuntu/Desktop/ViennaRNA-2.4.12/src/ViennaRNA/static'
make  install-am
make[4]: Entering directory '/home/ubuntu/Desktop/ViennaRNA-2.4.12/src/ViennaRNA/static'
make[5]: Entering directory '/home/ubuntu/Desktop/ViennaRNA-2.4.12/src/ViennaRNA/static'
make[5]: Nothing to be done for 'install-exec-am'.
make[5]: Nothing to be done for 'install-data-am'.
make[5]: Leaving directory '/home/ubuntu/Desktop/ViennaRNA-2.4.12/src/ViennaRNA/static'
make[4]: Leaving directory '/home/ubuntu/Desktop/ViennaRNA-2.4.12/src/ViennaRNA/static'
make[3]: Leaving directory '/home/ubuntu/Desktop/ViennaRNA-2.4.12/src/ViennaRNA/static'
make[3]: Entering directory '/home/ubuntu/Desktop/ViennaRNA-2.4.12/src/ViennaRNA'
  CC       fold_compound.lo
  CC       dist_vars.lo
  CC       part_func.lo
  CC       part_func_wrappers.lo
  CC       pf_fold.lo
  CC       treedist.lo
  CC       inverse.lo
  CC       ProfileDist.lo
  CC       RNAstruct.lo
  CC       mfe.lo
  CC       mfe_window.lo
  CC       mfe_wrappers.lo
  CC       mfe_window_wrappers.lo
  CC       fold.lo
  CC       stringdist.lo
  CC       subopt.lo
  CC       Lfold.lo
  CC       cofold.lo
  CC       part_func_co.lo
  CC       concentrations.lo
  CC       ProfileAln.lo
  CC       duplex.lo
  CC       alifold.lo
  CC       alipfold.lo
  CC       LPfold.lo
  CC       part_func_up.lo
  CC       ribo.lo
  CC       MEA.lo
  CC       mm.lo
  CC       2Dfold.lo
  CC       2Dpfold.lo
  CC       plex_functions.lo
  CC       ali_plex.lo
  CC       c_plex.lo
  CC       plex.lo
  CC       snofold.lo
  CC       snoop.lo
  CC       gquad.lo
  CC       perturbation_fold.lo
  CC       centroid.lo
  CC       model.lo
  CC       dp_matrices.lo
  CC       boltzmann_sampling.lo
  CC       bs_wrappers.lo
  CC       equilibrium_probs.lo
  CXX      ../libsvm-3.23/svm.lo
  CC       ../json/json.lo
  CC       alphabet.lo
  CC       sequence.lo
  CC       unstructured_domains.lo
  CC       grammar.lo
  CC       constraints/constraints.lo
  CC       constraints/SHAPE.lo
  CC       constraints/hard.lo
  CC       constraints/soft.lo
  CC       constraints/ligand.lo
  CCLD     libRNA_constraints.la
/usr/bin/ar: `u' modifier ignored since `D' is the default (see `U')
  CC       datastructures/basic_datastructures.lo
  CC       datastructures/lists.lo
  CC       datastructures/char_stream.lo
  CC       datastructures/stream_output.lo
  CC       datastructures/hash_tables.lo
  CC       datastructures/heap.lo
  CCLD     libRNA_datastructures.la
/usr/bin/ar: `u' modifier ignored since `D' is the default (see `U')
  CC       utils/utils.lo
  CC       utils/string_utils.lo
  CC       utils/structure_utils.lo
  CC       utils/structure_tree.lo
  CC       utils/msa_utils.lo
  CC       utils/higher_order_functions.lo
  CC       utils/cpu.lo
  CC       io/io_utils.lo
  CC       io/file_formats.lo
  CC       io/file_formats_msa.lo
  CC       search/BoyerMoore.lo
  CC       commands.lo
  CC       units.lo
  CC       combinatorics.lo
  CC       utils/svm_utils.lo
  CCLD     libRNA_utils.la
/usr/bin/ar: `u' modifier ignored since `D' is the default (see `U')
  CC       plotting/alignments.lo
  CC       plotting/layouts.lo
  CC       plotting/probabilities.lo
  CC       plotting/structures.lo
  CC       plotting/plot_utils.lo
  CC       plotting/naview.lo
  CC       plotting/RNApuzzler/RNApuzzler.lo
  CC       plotting/RNApuzzler/RNAturtle.lo
  CCLD     libRNA_plotting.la
/usr/bin/ar: `u' modifier ignored since `D' is the default (see `U')
  CC       params/io.lo
  CC       params/default.lo
  CC       params/params.lo
  CC       params/convert.lo
  CCLD     libRNA_params.la
/usr/bin/ar: `u' modifier ignored since `D' is the default (see `U')
  CC       eval.lo
  CC       eval_wrappers.lo
  CCLD     libRNA_eval.la
/usr/bin/ar: `u' modifier ignored since `D' is the default (see `U')
  CC       loops/external.lo
  CC       loops/external_bt.lo
  CC       loops/external_pf.lo
  CC       loops/hairpin.lo
  CC       loops/hairpin_bt.lo
  CC       loops/hairpin_pf.lo
  CC       loops/internal.lo
  CC       loops/internal_bt.lo
  CC       loops/internal_pf.lo
  CC       loops/multibranch.lo
  CC       loops/multibranch_bt.lo
  CC       loops/multibranch_pf.lo
  CCLD     libRNA_loops.la
/usr/bin/ar: `u' modifier ignored since `D' is the default (see `U')
  CC       move_set.lo
  CC       landscape/move.lo
  CC       landscape/findpath.lo
  CC       landscape/neighbor.lo
  CC       landscape/walk.lo
  CCLD     libRNA_landscape.la
/usr/bin/ar: `u' modifier ignored since `D' is the default (see `U')
  CC       utils/libRNA_utils_sse41_la-higher_order_functions_sse41.lo
  CCLD     libRNA_utils_sse41.la
/usr/bin/ar: `u' modifier ignored since `D' is the default (see `U')
  CC       utils/libRNA_utils_avx512_la-higher_order_functions_avx512.lo
  CCLD     libRNA_utils_avx512.la
/usr/bin/ar: `u' modifier ignored since `D' is the default (see `U')
  CXXLD    libRNA_conv.la
/usr/bin/ar: `u' modifier ignored since `D' is the default (see `U')
  CXXLD    libRNA.la
/usr/bin/ar: `u' modifier ignored since `D' is the default (see `U')
  CC       special_const.lo
  CC       ugly_bt.lo
  CCLD     libRNA_special_const.la
/usr/bin/ar: `u' modifier ignored since `D' is the default (see `U')
  GEN      libRNA.a
make[4]: Entering directory '/home/ubuntu/Desktop/ViennaRNA-2.4.12/src/ViennaRNA'
 /bin/mkdir -p '/usr/local/lib'
 /bin/bash ../../libtool   --mode=install /usr/bin/install -c   libRNA.la '/usr/local/lib'
libtool: install: /usr/bin/install -c .libs/libRNA.lai /usr/local/lib/libRNA.la
/usr/bin/install: cannot remove '/usr/local/lib/libRNA.la': Permission denied
Makefile:1177: recipe for target 'install-libLTLIBRARIES' failed
make[4]: *** [install-libLTLIBRARIES] Error 1
make[4]: Leaving directory '/home/ubuntu/Desktop/ViennaRNA-2.4.12/src/ViennaRNA'
Makefile:2087: recipe for target 'install-am' failed
make[3]: *** [install-am] Error 2
make[3]: Leaving directory '/home/ubuntu/Desktop/ViennaRNA-2.4.12/src/ViennaRNA'
Makefile:1926: recipe for target 'install-recursive' failed
make[2]: *** [install-recursive] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/ubuntu/Desktop/ViennaRNA-2.4.12/src/ViennaRNA'
Makefile:522: recipe for target 'install-recursive' failed
make[1]: *** [install-recursive] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/ubuntu/Desktop/ViennaRNA-2.4.12/src'
Makefile:667: recipe for target 'install-recursive' failed
make: *** [install-recursive] Error 1
```

Comment: Your non-privileged user does not have permission to write to `/usr/local/lib/` - you must either run the command with `sudo` or configure it to install to your home directory

Comment: i type sudo make install and get this message

Comment: Did you tried binary packages from https://www.tbi.univie.ac.at/RNA/#pack_ubuntu ? What is your Ubuntu version?

Comment: No i just download the source code from this website then configure it by typping ./configure
and type 
make install

Comment: According to [your next question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1141104/compilation-error-utils-h), I am guessing you have built the software successfully. Please consider posting an [answer](https://askubuntu.com/help/self-answer) or [deleting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5221/how-does-deleting-work-what-can-cause-a-post-to-be-deleted-and-what-does-that) this question.